# Is there an interface/type in golang for implementing > with generics?

Tags: go

I'm trying to find a comparable-like interface that I can use in the following code:

```golang
func SliceMax[T comparable](ts []T) (T, error) {
    if len(ts) == 0 {
        return 0, errors.New("cannot get max from empty slice")
    }

    m := ts[0]
    for _, e := range ts {
        if e > m {
            m = e
        }
    }
    return m, nil
}
```

But comparable doesn't work (it fails on the > sign). Is there a built in interface here or do I need to write my own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The predeclared type `comparable` is for things that are comparable with `==` and `!=` and doesn't include greater than or less than. You can use [`constraints.Ordered`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/constraints#Ordered) from the go exp repository, although you'll also have to change `return 0, ...` to something like `var zero T; return zero, ...` because for example strings are comparable but don't have 0.

It's not directly relevant to your question, but as a small code-review comment, a value of type `[]T` is a slice, not an array (an array has a fixed size), so I'd probably call the function `SliceMax` and I'd try to avoid including the type (ie: slice or array) in the name of the argument that's currently named `typeArray` (it's not an array of type -- it's neither an array nor are its elements a type), and pick something generic like `ts` although I know that's not to everyone's taste.